# Why doesn't this regex match if a parallel of it does?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I am a beginner at writing regexes and have a question.

From what I understand, if I wanted to validate that a string had something other than lowercase letters in it, I'd use this regex:

`[^a-z]`

I would use it because this character class matches anything that contains non lowercase letters, yet when passed this string:

`apple 12345`

```
      ^not a lowercase letter.
```

it comes up with no matches.

If I were to pass it this, however:

`[^0-9]`

the regex is

(I am using the latest version of Regetron to test my expressions)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your tools. Both your regexes match: see [demo1](http://regex101.com/r/fQ1iD5/30) and [demo2](http://regex101.com/r/fQ1iD5/32) The first finds chars that are not lowercase letters. The second finds chars that are not ASCII digits.

Comment: If you're looking for matching characters that are neither `a-z` nor `0-9`, then see `[^a-z0-9]`. If you're looking for matching this string, see `[a-z0-9 ]`. (Whitespace is intended.)

Comment: that's what i answered.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depending on the programming language or regex library you use, a match may or may not be **anchored**. An unanchored match will find a match anywhere in the search string. An anchored match will have implicit `^` and/or `$` anchors, tying the regex to the beginning (or entirety) of the search string.

If your regex library is anchored, and you want to emulate the unanchored experience, add `.*` to both ends.

```
.*[^a-z].*
```

Comment: +1, nice troubleshooting, that sounds exactly like what is happening to Joe. :)

Comment: Could you provide any more clarification on the meaning of anchored, or more specifically _where_ an anchored expression looks for a character matching the class? Thanks for the help and the speedy response.